# How do you cite from a presentation or poster at a conference?

Tags: conference, citations, poster

For example, a presentation whose PDF is listed at http://www.astro.ex.ac.uk/exoclimes/2012/pdf/talks/Day02_Ferreira.pdf?

And what if the presentation doesn't have a publicly available URL? How would the citation style differ from that of a poster?

Comment: It's worth checking with the conference... for example, [Society for Neuroscience](http://www.sfn.org/) poster abstracts have a [citation style listed at the bottom of every page (scroll to bottom of page, under "support" heading)](http://www.abstractsonline.com/Plan/ViewAbstract.aspx?sKey=284b8d58-16d3-4ee4-b333-accf27821c11&cKey=02591234-7ebf-4f73-9db7-5f5cbe1a1b18&mKey=%7b8334BE29-8911-4991-8C31-32B32DD5E6C8%7d).

Comment: I would try to avoid citing a presentation or poster in the first place. It won't make a very good reference for your readers, since not only may it be hard to find, but it won't have a complete description of what the previous authors did. Instead, I would contact the authors of the poster, and ask if they have a paper about their project, or at least a preprint, and then cite that.

Answer (score 8):

The specifics of the citation would depend on the citation style you are using. I am most familiar with Chicago style. To cite the presentation you've linked to in **Chicago** style, I would put:

David Ferreira, et al., "Climate of an Earth-like Aquaplanet: the high-obliquity case and the tidally-locked case" (presentation, Exoclimes 2012, Aspen, CO, January 16–20, 2012), accessed June 8, 2012, http://www.astro.ex.ac.uk/exoclimes/2012/pdf/talks/Day02_Ferreira.pdf.

Following these guidelines: http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/717/08/

For APA style, you would only cite a presentation in a reference list if there is a tangible remnant ("recoverable data") of the presentation (e.g., slides posted on a website). The citation would look like:

Ferreira, D., Marshall, J., O'Gorman, P., Seager, S. & Lau, H. (January 2012). *Climate of an Earth-Like Aquaplanet: the high-obliquity case and the tidally-locked case.* Paper presented at Exoclimes 2012, Aspen, Co.

For more examples in APA citation, look here: http://citationonline.net/CitationHelp/csg04-manuscripts-apa.htm#53

Answer (score 3):

To supplement Nate's comments, what I have usually seen is "personal communication". The poster isn't yet peer-reviewed and if it has yet to be written up as a manuscript and you can't cite it as a paper that is "in press", "personal communication" is a good substitute.

Comment: I find "personal communication" rather poor as a citation. How can one look that up?

Comment: Well if it is personal communication with Dave Clarke, it gives people an idea. At least it is better than trying to cite a url that may not exist in a year.

Comment: I don't even remember the conversation ...

Comment: @Dave Clarke, Touche

Comment: "Personal communication" is what you write when you've given up on citing anything that could actually help the reader, and just want to give credit to your friend.  Which is about as much as citing a presentation accomplishes.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that one commonly used weight update strategies for neural networks, RMSProp, was first introduced in a [slide](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=rmsprop+&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22):

[image]

Given the number of citations, it should give you plenty of examples on how to cite a slide.

One common citation format:

> T. Tieleman and G. Hinton. Lecture 6.5-rmsprop: Divide
>   the gradient by a running average of its recent magnitude.
>   COURSERA: Neural Networks for Machine Learning, 4,
>   2012.